# PgUP and PgDN on a Macbook

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook

The one thing that really annoys me about my Macbook is that it's missing the Home, End, Page Up and Page Down buttons. The latter ones I especially miss when interacting with particular console applications (`less`, for example). Is there any way to assign them to keys I don't actually use, like the buttons up top bring up Dashboard (I have that disabled) and such?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On a MacBook:

- `Home` is `Cmd` + ↑ / `Fn` + ←
- `End` is `Cmd` + ↓ / `Fn` + →
- `PageUp` is `Fn` + ↑
- `PageDown` is `Fn` + ↓

Comment: Also `Fn` + [right arrow] for end and `Fn` + [left arrow] for home. I find that easier to remember, since the modifier key is the same as for page up and down.

Comment: On a macbook with win7, `Cmd` + ↑ and `Cmd` + ↓ work like `Win` + ↑ and `Win` + ↓, ie. cycle through maximixe, restore and minimize.

Comment: Ah, MacBook, making things simpler since.... ?

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, the missing keys on Macbooks (and many Windows notebooks) are something extremely annoying.

Normally, on Macbook keyboards, you get

<kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd> with <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>

and

<kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDown</kbd> with <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>

However, as you noticed, this doesn't work in Terminal apps like nano, Midnight Commander, less, etc.

In Terminal, you need to add Shift to let them "pass through" to Terminal.

<kbd>Home</kbd> : <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>

<kbd>End</kbd>  : <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>

<kbd>PgUp</kbd> : <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>

<kbd>PgDn</kbd> : <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>

Of course, when what you really need happens to be <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> ... forget it! (Or connect a real keyboard)

And Midnight Commander users will want to know that the missing Insert key can obtained with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: What about applications that want you to press PgUp and PgDn at the same time? (Second Life is the one I'm thinking of...)

Comment: *"connect a real keyboard"* Or perhaps, those NumPad-only things? Just turn the *Num Lock* off and viola!

Answer (score 2):

You can use PgUp and PgDwn with 'Fn'+'Up' and 'Fn'+Down'.

Answer (score 1):

In text editors such as TextEdit or Pages:

- Page Up (reposition cursor) is <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>
- Page Down (reposition cursor) is <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In less (in similar terminal apps paginating content) you can use:

<kbd>space</kbd>: page forward

<kbd>backspace</kbd>: page backward

or

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>: page forward

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>: page backward